# Angular.js How to Inject $scope into directive() for $scope.on()?

Tags: angularjs

for the directive I wrote, how do I get $scope in there so I can do $scope.$on()? I could inject $rootScope, but I want to use $scope to catch the broadcast.

```
angular.module('monitorApp')
.run(function($rootScope, $interval) {
            $interval(function(){
                $rootScope.$broadcast('ONE_SEC');
            }, 1000);
});
```

---

```
angular.module('monitorApp')
.directive("countDown", [ 'sseHandler', function (sseHandler) {
    console.log(sseHandler.broadcastStamp.cpuResult);
    return {
        scope: {
            countFrom: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, $scope){
           scope.countFrom = sseHandler.broadcastStamp.cpuResult;
           $scope.$on('ONE_SEC', function(scope) {
               sseHandler.broadcastStamp.cpuResult--;
           });
        }
    }
}]);
```

---

**UPDATE**: with scope injection, I get error:
`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- countDownDirective`

```
angular.module('monitorApp')
.directive("countDown", [ 'sseHandler', '$scope', function (sseHandler, $scope) {
    console.log(sseHandler.broadcastStamp.cpuResult);
    return {
        scope: {
            countFrom: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, $scope){
           scope.countFrom = sseHandler.broadcastStamp.cpuResult;
           $scope.$on('ONE_SEC', function(scope, $scope) {
               sseHandler.broadcastStamp.cpuResult--;
           });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I tried scope.on() but .on() doesn't exist on that scope.

Comment: There's no `on`, just `$on`. The first three arguments to `link` are always scope, element and attributes; you can name them, differently, but you always get the same things. And don't ever use both `scope` and `$scope`, that's just a confusing non-sense.

Comment: I thought so also...but how do I achieve what I am trying to do in the directive without useing both `scope` and `$scope`?

Comment: You know you can just use the `scope` variable - `scope.$on`, right?

Comment: Thanks...it stopped complaining with scope.$on(). I guess I used scope.on() before.

Comment: Take the first argument of `link`, no matter how you call it. It's the scope associated with the element the directive is placed on. You may want to use `$rootScope` for listening to events, but you don't need to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `scope.$on`, you don't need to try and inject `$scope`:

```
scope.$on('ONE_SEC', function() {
           //do stuff
});
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/G2r7G/

Answer (score 0):

The link gives arguments scope, element and attributes in that order. In your link you are actually assigning `element` to `$scope`

To inject the $scope you inject it at the same place you're injecting ssehandler

`directive("countDown", [ 'sseHandler', '$scope', function (sseHandler, $scope)....`

Comment: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- countDownDirective` with using `.directive("countDown", [ 'sseHandler', '$scope', function (sseHandler, $scope) {}`

Comment: Put $scope in your run function too